# add layered navigation to magento tag page

Tags: magento, tags, layered-navigation

For tag page, I mean this kind of page:

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/tag/product/list/tagId/448/

I have add the following code to mytheme/layout/tag.xml after the line

```
<label>Tagged Products List</label>
```

//code added

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

But the layered navigation does not show.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution?